# Playing HD video accelerated by GPU? (Linux)

Tags: linux, gpu, hdvideo

I know that this laptop (Asus UL30A) does support playing HD material with the help of the GPU on windows. The question is how can I do this under linux? The CPU load as is implies that this is not activated. I assume that it's limited to a handful of codecs. But which player supports this, if its even supported at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe only ( limited) nVidia cards are supported, via the [vdpau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) support. As of now, <s>only the latest versions of Mplayer/SMplayer</s> supported players include Mplayer/SMplater, Xine, XBMC, Boxee, GStreamer. You will need an relatively newer ( 8xxx series, I believe ) graphics card, running on `nvidia` driver, not the open source `nv` driver. [Short howto do it in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1037625)

Comment: So with Intel gpu I'm lost?

Comment: @data_jepp I'm afraid, as of now, yes.

Answer (score 1):

With AMD/ATI hardware the only solution for your H.264 videos without tearing is to setup on smplayer/mplayer on video output -> OpenGL (fast ATI cards). Assuming your notebook is with Intel HD video you don't have much of a choise.